# Strange Drupal behaviour after update

Tags: 7, updating

After updating Drupal from 7.15 to 7.16, I noticed a strange behavior.

If my custom module is enabled, the website design is broken in Internet Explorer. I don't see some parts of website: The front page shows only slideshow, I don't see filters or even the whole pages. If a custom module I am using is disabled, everything is OK. I tried to downgrade again to 7.15, but I still have the same error.

I really don't understand why it happened, as I didn't have any problems with Internet Explorer, and my module before the update.

Can anyone help me with my problem?

This is the code used from my custom module.

```
/**@file This module provides custom functions    */

/** Unset these form elements from the comment_form using hook_form_alter */

function custom_module_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['author']['name']['#access'] = FALSE;
  return $form;
}

/** Implements hook_block_info(). This hook declares what blocks are provided by the module.*/
function custom_module_block_info() {
  $blocks['contact_block_form'] = array(
    'info' => t('Contact Form'),
  );

  return $blocks;
}

/** Implements hook_block_view(). This hook generates the contents of the blocks themselves. */
function custom_module_block_view($delta = '') {
  //The $delta parameter tells us which block is being requested.
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'contact_block_form':
      $block['subject'] = t('');
      // Load contact pages inc as the form definition sits there.
      module_load_include('inc', 'contact', 'contact.pages');
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('contact_site_form');
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}

/** Views - Exposed Filter Form Theming  */

function custom_module_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'location') {
    $form['field_location_tag_tid']['#options']['All'] = t('- choose region -');
    $form['field_poselok_tag_tid_option_limit']['#options']['All'] = t('- choose city -');
$form['field_poselok_tag_tid_option_limit']['#states'] = array(
      'disabled' => array('select[id="edit-field-location-tag-tid"]' => array('value' => 'All')),
    );

    $form['type_1']['#options']['All'] = t('- choose gallery type -');
    $form['field_author_tid']['#options']['All'] = t('- choose gallery author -');
    $form['field_author_tid']['#states'] = array(
      'invisible' => array('select[name="type_1"]' => array('value' => 'gallery')),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check for dblogs /admin/reports/dblog , i believe "website design" is something you are talking about theme and not White Screen of Death

Comment: Its all depend on the code of your custom module. Are you adding any html or block using your custom module ?

Comment: ^this.  Without seeing, or at least having an idea of, what your custom module does this question is impossibly to answer.

Comment: I added a code in edit

Comment: /admin/reports/dblog - didn't show something strange or unusual

Comment: Is the closing `?>` something you've put there?  If so, it [shouldn't be there](http://drupal.org/coding-standards#phptags).

Comment: I removed `?>` but it still the same: in all browsers website looks correctly except IE

Comment: If it's just IE I'd start by looking through the markup with the developer tools and see if you have an unclosed tag.  IE is pretty funny about that.

Comment: The problem is that IE by default used Document Mode: Quirks. I changed it to IE9 standarts and now everything is OK. But now I have another question how to say IE use IE9 standarts or IE8/IE7 when showing my website. Because if user will have Document Mode: Quirks by default it will cause the same problems that I had today.

Comment: I found the following: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IEVersion">` I hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">` in  and now my website looks fine in IE.